# Update multiple related tables using Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, openjpa

I have two tables `Employee` and `Address` having `one-to-one` relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
      ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
      EMP_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      PHONE_ID BIGINT,
      DELETED BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
      CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT1 FOREIGN KEY (PHONE_ID)
      REFERENCES PHONE (ID)
)


CREATE TABLE PHONE(
     ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
     PH_NUMBER VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     DELETED BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
 )
```

I am using Spring Data REST.

Q1.  I want to expose a single data rest repository method to update `DELETED` column for both `EMPLOYEE` and `PHONE.

Something like below:

```
TestRepository implements CrudRepository{
   @Query(value="update both table query", native=false)
   public void updateBoth();
}
```

Q2. Is doing so even possible using Spring data REST.

**PLEASE NOTE**: I do not want to use native query, i.e. `@Query(value="", native="true")`

Answer (score 3):

You have to find the balance between using the framework properly and overusing it.

Spring Data REST is to expose your repositories to HTTP but you can't solve everything with it.

The proper way here is to create a custom Controller and implement the functionality you want with proper transaction management to have the data integrity you need.